# Two Sum Leetcode

Tags: c#, programming-challenge, hash-map, k-sum

Looking for some feedback on the [Two Sum LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/) problem. Looking for feedback on code style in general, use of var, variable naming and initialization, return placement, and any other feedback or optimizations I could make.

**Problem**

Given an array of integers, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to a specific target.

You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution, and you may not use the same element twice.

```
Example:
Given nums = [2, 7, 11, 15], target = 9,

Because nums[0] + nums[1] = 2 + 7 = 9,
return [0, 1].
```

**My solution**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Solution {
    public int[] TwoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
        var numsDictionary = new Dictionary<int, int>();

        int complement = 0;
        for(int i=0; i < nums.Count(); i++) 
        {            
            complement = target - nums[i];
            int index = 0;
            if(numsDictionary.TryGetValue(complement, out index))
            {
                int[] twoSumSolution = {index, i};
                return twoSumSolution;
            }                                                         

            if(!numsDictionary.ContainsKey(nums[i]))
            {
                numsDictionary.Add(nums[i], i);
            }            
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Was it specified _how_ you needed to solve this? You're solving it by looking for the complement you know you need; but these types of challenges often entail iteratively (brute force) checking all elements of a list; as the iterative logic is often the point of such a challenge.

Comment: it was not, one sample solution did you use brute and another used an approach similar to one pass dictionary / map

Comment: Any reason you call the variable the complement and not the difference?

Comment: No particular reason, changing to difference is an optimization I can make for readability.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- Most C# developers will place opening braces on a new line. If you do this as well then you make it easier to read the code by others.
- `complement` and `index` should use `var` "type" as well
- `twoSumSolution` isn't really needed and is only adding noise to the code.
- I like to use `if (bool == false)` instead of `if (!bool)` because I can grasp it at first glance without wondering wether I see a exclamation sign or not.
- Instead of using the [`Count()`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,41ef9e39e54d0d0b) extension method I prefer using the `Length` property for arrays. Using `Count()` will envolve a soft cast to `ICollection<T>` and a `null` check which just isn't needed.
- checking if `complement > 0` will remove unneeded calls to `TryGetValue()`, but has implications on certain inputs like `target = 0` and an array `[-3, 7, 3]`.

Implementing the mentioned points will lead to

```
public int[] TwoSum(int[] nums, int target)
{
    var numsDictionary = new Dictionary<int, int>();

    var complement = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++)
    {
        complement = target - nums[i];
        var index = 0;
        if (complement > 0 && numsDictionary.TryGetValue(complement, out index))
        {
            return new int[] { index, i };
        }

        if (numsDictionary.ContainsKey(nums[i]) == false)
        {
            numsDictionary.Add(nums[i], i);
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: all great comments, thanks for the feedback. great use of `var`, much easier to focus in on the output of the function `int[]`.

Comment: Two nitpicks: (1) `var` isn’t a type. (2) I think your first advice is bad: if this is indeed the general C# style (never heard that, but haven’t used C# much in the last years), then the consensus is simply wrong. It’s objectively less readable because it wastes vertical space on syntactic noise. :-( Similar for your fourth advice: boolean literals have no place outside of initialisations.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: `var` is an implicit strongly type specification - resolved at compile time. About your argue about brackets, I thing you're up against a whole community. I agree with your last point though ;-)

Comment: @KonradRudolph about boolean, as long as your eyes are good there isn't a problem using `!` but if they get worse you will be glad to see `false` instead.

Comment: @Heslacher Regarding `var`: I know what is. But it *isn’t* a type, contrary to what your answer says. Regarding the `bool`: So put a space between the operator and the rest of the expression. Personally I prefer languages that spell the operator out for readability (`not` instead of `!`) but since this is C#…

Comment: WRONG ANSWER thrown by LeetCode test case! Your code fails for input [0,4,3,0], target 0, expected [0, 3]

Comment: `complement > 0` is an extra check that will throw errors for negative numbers

Answer (score 6):

Some minor points:

1) You don't really need the `complement` variable, so just do the math in the call to TryGetValue().

2) If `int[] nums` are all positive you may `continue` the loop if `nums[i] > target`.

3) It is stated that there is only one solution per input, so you can skip the check `if (!numsDictionary.ContainsKey(nums[i]))`. This will never be true for the nums that add up to the target. As for the rest of nums it doesn't matter.

---

All in all it could be reduced to this (for C# 7.0):

```
public int[] TwoSumReview(int[] nums, int target)
{
  Dictionary<int, int> numsDictionary = new Dictionary<int, int>();

  for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++)
  {
    int num = nums[i];

    // You can uncomment this if nums are all positive
    //if (num > target) { continue; }

    if (numsDictionary.TryGetValue(target - num, out int index))
    {          
      return new [] { index, i }; 
    }

    numsDictionary[num] = i;
  }

  return null;
}
```

Comment: Good catch about `ContainsKey()`

Comment: any reason not to use Array.IndexOf instead of to search for the complement within the array? I just tried both ways and Array.IndexOf was faster

Comment: @JackMarchetti: I think that may be true for small data sets, but `Array.IndexOf`is an O(n) operation, so that approach is potentially O(n^2), where the above is an O(n*1) because looking up in a dictionary is (close to) O(1). If I understand you right, but why not write your suggestion as an answer?

Comment: @HenrikHansen you're right. I was processing a small aray that was sorted and that's why it was fast. Once it expanded out it was very slow.

Answer (score 2):

Dictionary can be initialized to an initial capacity
No purpose to `index = 0`

```
public static int[] TwoSum(int[] nums, int target)
{
    int numsLength = nums.Length;
    if(numsLength <= 1)
    {
        return null;
    }
    Dictionary<int, int> numsDictionary = new Dictionary<int, int>(numsLength);
    int complement;
    int index;
    int num;
    numsDictionary.Add(nums[0], 0);
    for (int i = 1; i < numsLength; i++)
    {
        num = nums[i];
        complement = target - num;
        if (numsDictionary.TryGetValue(complement, out index))
        {
            return new int[] { index, i };
        }
        if (!numsDictionary.ContainsKey(num))
        {
            numsDictionary.Add(num, i);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```